# Function that calculates, mean, variance and skewness at the same time in a dataframe

Tags: r, function

I have this dataframe

```
um dois tres
1.2 1.9 0.1
1.2 1.1 2
2.2 1.2 0.4
3.0 1.8 2.6
```

and I need to calculate in the same function the mean, variance and skewness of the dataframe. I have the functions separate.
Any suggestions?

```
mean <- function(x){
  sum(x)/length(x)
}

variance <- function(x){
    n <- length(x)
    m <- mean(x)
    (1/(n-1))*sum((x-m)^2)
}

skewness <- function(x) {
  n <- length(x)
  v <- var(x)
  m <- mean(x)
  third.moment <- (1/(n - 2))*sum((x - m)^3)
  third.moment/(var(x)^(3/2))
}
```

Comment: What does "of the dataframe" mean? Calculate values for each column, or for all numbers in all columns combined?

Comment: See the `moments` package for the skewness function.

Answer (score 1):

```
dput(data)
structure(list(um = c(1.2, 1.2, 2.2, 3), dois = c(1.9, 1.1, 1.2, 1.8), tres = c(0.1, 2, 0.4, 2.6)), class = "data.frame", row.names = c(NA,-4L))


# to use the function skewnewss install and load the package e1071
library(e1071)
sapply(data, function(x) c(means = mean(x), vars = var(x), skews = skewness(x)))
```

The output generates the required calculations in one go, for each of the input columns:

```
             um      dois       tres
   means 1.9000000 1.5000000 1.27500000
   vars  0.7600000 0.1666667 1.47583333
   skews  0.2535648 0.0000000 0.05788459
```

Comment: Note that `e1071::skewness` takes the option `type = ` from 1-3. Whilst 3 is the default, 1 is the "typical" definition. See also `moments::skewness`, which returns values as for type = 1.

Comment: I have to create one function that calculates mean, variance and skewness for each column. I have an error when I execute sappy: "Error in var(x) : is.atomic(x) is not TRUE"

Answer (score 1):

You don't explain whether "of the dataframe" means "by column". Let's assume it does and use `tidyr::gather()` to reshape the data from wide to long, then `dplyr::summarise()` for the calculations. Assume the dataframe is named `data1` and using `moments::skewness`:

```
library(tidyr)
library(dplyr)
library(moments)

data1 %>%
  gather(Var, Val) %>% 
  group_by(Var) %>% 
  summarise(Mean = mean(Val), 
            Vari = var(Val), 
            Skew = skewness(Val))

# A tibble: 3 x 4
  Var    Mean  Vari   Skew
  <chr> <dbl> <dbl>  <dbl>
1 dois   1.5  0.167 0     
2 tres   1.28 1.48  0.0891
3 um     1.9  0.76  0.390
```

If you want values for all numbers, not by column, just omit the `group_by`.

If you want to use your own function - no need since R supplies them in this case - but you could just substitute their names.