# Row wise normality, skewness and kurtosis in one command

Tags: r, distribution, skew, rowwise

My data is:

```
X0 X1 X2 X3 category
0  15 4  4  TAH
0  2  5  0  MAT
0  11 9  0  BIO
```

I want to calculate row-wise *normality*, *skewness* and *kurtosis*. The main reason is that I have categories over different rows (in a dedicated column). Is there a function that can achieve this functionality?

I have been trying to do this using the `moments` package and the `dplyr` package, similar to this post:
[Function that calculates, mean, variance and skewness at the same time in a dataframe](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/55054837/function-that-calculates-mean-variance-and-skewness-at-the-same-time-in-a-data/55055116#55055116).
But their solution is column wise not row wise.

```
df3 %>%
  gather(category, Val) %>% 
  group_by(category) %>% 
  summarise(Mean = mean(Val), 
            Vari = var(Val), 
            Skew = skewness(Val))
```

For normality, I have tried the following command separately for each row:

```
shapiro.test(df3[1,])
```

Any help on this would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: **Note:** Better use the `skewness` function of the `e1071` package (v1.7.8) which is better established than the `moments` package (v0.14).

Comment: Thanks for the suggestion. I wonder why the results are so different using the two packages: ```e1071``` and ```moments```

Comment: Try`type=1`. Compare: `identical(e1071::skewness(unlist(d[3, -5]), type=1), moments::skewness(unlist(d[3, -5])))`. Read `?e1071::skewness` to decide which _type_ you want to use.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can use `rowwise` -

```
library(dplyr)
library(tidyr)

df %>%
  rowwise() %>%
  mutate(Mean = mean(c_across(X0:X3)), 
         Vari = var(c_across(X0:X3)),
         Shap = shapiro.test(c_across(X0:X3))$p.value,
         Skew = moments::skewness(c_across(X0:X3))) %>%
  ungroup

#     X0    X1    X2    X3 category  Mean    Vari   Shap   Skew
#  <int> <int> <int> <int> <chr>    <dbl>   <dbl>   <dbl>  <dbl>
#1     0    15     4     4 TAH       5.75   41.583  0.232  0.84778 
#2     0     2     5     0 MAT       1.75   5.5833  0.220  0.68925 
#3     0    11     9     0 BIO       5      34      0.110  0.058244
```

Similar to your attempt you may get the data in long format and calculate the statistics for each `category` (rowwise).

```
df %>%
  pivot_longer(cols = -category) %>%
  group_by(category) %>%
  summarise(Mean = mean(value), 
            Vari = var(value), 
            Skew = moments::skewness(value))
```

Comment: Thanks for the solution. Could we also include some sort of normality test in the above code? Like ```shapiro.test()```

Comment: Sure, you can use `shapiro = list(shapiro.test(c_across(X0:X3))))` to save the test or  do `shapiro = shapiro.test(c_across(X0:X3))$p.value` to extract only the p-value.

Answer (score 0):

You may try

```
library(PerformanceAnalytics)

df %>%
  select(category, X0:X3) %>%
  t %>%
  as.data.frame %>%
  row_to_names(row_number = 1) %>%
  mutate(TAH = as.numeric(TAH),
         MAT = as.numeric(MAT),
         BIO = as.numeric(BIO)) %>%
  sapply(., function(x) list(mean = mean(x), var = var(x), skew = skewness(x), kur = kurtosis(x)))

     TAH        MAT       BIO       
mean 5.75       1.75      5         
var  41.58333   5.583333  34        
skew 0.8477758  0.6892545 0.05824397
kur  -0.8325348 -1.141902 -1.922722
```